# Deserializing JSON array with JSON-B

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jsonb-api

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON Array with JSONB.

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "animal": "dog",
    "age": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "animal": "cat",
    "age": "5"
  }
]
```

**Controller**

```
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();    
Animal animal;
AnimalsList animalsList;

public AnimalsList getAnimals() {
    try {
        animalsList = jsonb.fromJson("[{\"id\":\"1\",\"animal\":\"dog\",\"age\":\"3\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"animal\":\"cat\",\"age\":\"5\"}]", AnimalsList.class);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return animalsList;
}
```

**AnimalsList**

```
public class AnimalsList implements Serializable{

    private List<Animal> list;

    public AnimalsList() {
    }

    public AnimalsList(List<Animal> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    // getter & setter
}
```

**Animal**

```
public class Animal implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private String animal;
    private int age;

    public Animal() {
    }

    public Animal(int id, String animal, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.animal = animal;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // getter & setter
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't deserialize JSON array into: class com.model.AnimalsList
```

Comment: Your json has an array type, you can't deserialize it to a single object (a `AnimalsList` object). You may try to deserialize your json directly into a `List<Animal>` .

Comment: @Arnaud: Like this `List<Animal> animals = jsonb.fromJson("[{...}]", List.class)`?

Comment: Maybe with `new ArrayList<Animal>(){}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` instead of `List.class` , see here : https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/users-guide.html .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written in the comment of [Arnaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612858/arnaud), this [guide](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/docs/user-guide.html#mapping-a-collection) shows a solution:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
dogs.add(falco);
dogs.add(cassidy);

// Create Jsonb and serialize
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
String result = jsonb.toJson(dogs);

// Deserialize back
dogs = jsonb.fromJson(result, new ArrayList<Dog>(){}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
```

Comment: The code works, but not when wrapped by the generic method.  The generic method throws:

`WARNING: Generic bound not found for type T declared in public static java.util.List fromJsonArray(jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb,java.lang.String).`

Comment: Followed by: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class my.package.MyType (java.util.HashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; my.package.MyType is in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: @ARX: The section with the generic method is removed from the post

Answer (score -2):

If you're not restricted to just use JSON-B you can do it with ObjectMapper by TypeReferencing.

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Animal> animals = objectMapper.readValue(json , new TypeReference<List<Animal>>(){});
```

Comment: The question was specifically about JSON-B